# How do I automate adding a string above a specific one with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a document that needs fixing. To keep it simple in it's pattern I messed up, and to fix it, there's a couple thousand instances that need to be inserted above another one.

For example: (Note, these are not the actual strings, simplified them with numbers)

```
1  
1  
3  
1   
1
```

But, I need it to be:

```
1  
1  
2  
3  
1   
1
```

My idea was that in Notepad++, I could automate a search for every instance of 3, enter a line above it, and enter the 2 itself in the new blank space.

Since I need to do this a couple thousand times, doing it manually is a no-go in terms of saving time.

Comment: then why don't you try your idea first?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to operate your idea, do this:

```
In Replace window:
-  Fill in "Find what": 3
-  Fill in "Replace with": 2\n3
-  In Search Mode: Choose "Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x ...)
```

Then just Replace All